# how can I compute number of finger? (openCV + contour Detection)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv, computer-vision, contour

I start to find hand contour with `findContour` but when I want to compute the finger with `convHull2` and `convextyDefect` I do not know what to do.

Could you please help me?  Here is my code:

```
if( cascade1 )
{
static CvMemStorage* storage4 = 0;
static CvMemStorage* storage5 = 0;
static CvMemStorage* storage6 = 0;
static CvMemStorage* storage7 = 0;


CvSeq* contours;
CvSeq* hand_contour = NULL;

// There can be more than one hand in an image. So create a growable sequence of hands.
// Detect the objects and store them in the sequence
CvSeq* handsO = cvHaarDetectObjects( img, cascade1, storage1,1.1, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,cvSize(40, 40) );

storage4 = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
storage5 = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
storage6 = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
storage7 = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

cvClearMemStorage( storage4 );
cvClearMemStorage( storage5 );
cvClearMemStorage( storage6 );
cvClearMemStorage( storage7 );


// Loop the number of hands found.
for( i = 0; i < (handsO ? handsO->total : 0); i++ )
{
    // Create a new rectangle for drawing the hand
    CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( handsO, i );

    // Find the dimensions of the hand,and scale it if necessary
    pt1.x = r->x*scale;
    pt2.x = (r->x+r->width)*scale;
    pt1.y = r->y*scale;
    pt2.y = (r->y+r->height)*scale;

    /////////////////////  start hand contour detection////////////////////////

    // after finding the hand set it as the area of intrest of the image so all of the functions after that will apply only to that area
    cvSetImageROI(Rhand, cvRect(r->x*scale, r->y*scale, r->width*scale, r->height*scale));
    /*
    / prepare the image to the findContour function
    / 1- convert it to gray
    / 2- threshhold it
    / 3- find the edge
    */
    cvShowImage( "gray hand", Rhand);
    cvThreshold( Rhand, Rhand, 1, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );
    cvShowImage( "Threshold hand", Rhand);
    cvCanny(Rhand, Rhand, 1, 3, 5);
    cvShowImage( "Edge hand", Rhand);

    /*
    // cloasing after threshold to test if it will be a beter result 
    IplConvKernel* kernel = 0;
    kernel = cvCreateStructuringElementEx(5,5,0,0, CV_SHAPE_RECT);
    cvDilate(Rhand,Rhand,kernel,1);
    cvErode(Rhand,Rhand,kernel,1);
    */


    // find all contour  in the image
    cvFindContours(Rhand,storage4,&contours,sizeof(CvContour),CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));

//  printf("\ncontour num%d",contours->total);
    // find the beggest contour and make it as the hand by comaring the area of each contour
    double area=0,biggestArea=0;
    while(contours)
    {
        area = fabs( cvContourArea( contours, CV_WHOLE_SEQ ) );
        //printf("\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\%f",area);

        if ( area > biggestArea) 
        {
        biggestArea = area; 
        hand_contour = contours;
        //printf("\n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\biggest\\\\\\\\\\\\\\%d",hand_contour->total);
        };

        contours  =  contours->h_next;
    }

    cvWaitKey(0);       

    if(hand_contour)
    {

        hand_contour = cvApproxPoly( hand_contour, sizeof(CvContour), storage7, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, 3, 1 );
        CvRect rect = cvBoundingRect(hand_contour, 1 );
        CvBox2D box = cvMinAreaRect2( hand_contour, storage6 );
        //draw the rectangle arround the contour
        cvRectangle( img, cvPoint(rect.x, rect.y + rect.height), cvPoint(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y), CV_RGB(255, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0 );

        // preparing to detect the finger and compute/ draw them
        CvSeq* hull = cvConvexHull2( hand_contour, 0, CV_CLOCKWISE, 0 );
        int numOfHull =hull->total;
        CvPoint*  hullPoints;
        hullPoints = ( CvPoint *)malloc((hull->total)*sizeof(CvSeq));
        cvCvtSeqToArray(hull,hullPoints);           

        CvSeq* defect = cvConvexityDefects( hand_contour, hull, storage5 );
        int numOfdefect =defect->total;
        CvConvexityDefect* defectArray;
        defectArray = (CvConvexityDefect*)malloc(sizeof(CvConvexityDefect)*numofdefect);  
        cvCvtSeqToArray(defect,defectArray); 

        /*int h1,h2;
        for(i=0; i<numofHull-1; i++)  
        { 
            h1=hull[i];
            h2=hull[i+1];
            cvLine(img, defectArray[h1],defectArray[h2],CV_RGB(255,255,255),1, CV_AA, 0 );  
        }
        int h3=hull[numofHull-1],h4=hull[0];
        cvLine(img, defectArray[h3],defectArray[h4],CV_RGB(255,255,255),1, CV_AA, 0 );  
       // Free memory.            
       free(defectArray);  
       free(hull);  */

       int m=10;
        //cvPolyLine(img,&hullPoints,&m,CV_RGB( 0, 0, 100),1,8,0);
        //cvPolyLine( img, &hullPoints, &m, 2, 0, CV_RGB(0,0,100),10, CV_AA, 0);

        cvCircle( img, cvPoint(pt1.x, pt1.y), 3, CV_RGB(255, 128, 0), 3, 8, 0 );    
        cvCircle( img, cvPoint(box.center.x, box.center.y), 3, CV_RGB(75, 243, 243), 1, 8, 0 );
        cvEllipse( img, cvPoint(pt1.x, pt1.y), cvSize(box.size.height/2, box.size.width/2), box.angle, 0, 360, CV_RGB(220, 0, 120), 2, 8, 0 );
        cvDrawContours( Rhand, hand_contour,  CV_RGB( 0, 200, 100), CV_RGB( 100, 0, 0), 1, 1, 8, cvPoint(pt1.x,pt1.y));
        cvDrawContours( img, hand_contour,  CV_RGB( 0, 200, 100), CV_RGB( 100, 0, 0), 1, 1, 8, cvPoint(pt1.x,pt1.y));
        cvShowImage( "Rhand after draw contour", Rhand);
        cvShowImage( "img After draw contour", img);

        cvResetImageROI(Rhand);
        ///////////////////// End hand contour detection////////////////////////
}
// Draw the rectangle in the input image
 cvRectangle( img, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 3, 8, 0 );
}
cvClearSeq(handsO);
}
```

Comment: You may assume that the number of fingers in a hand is five. You'll have great accuracy with this code: `int CountFingers(cv::Mat& img) { return 5; }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the code since I'm just learning this myself but since the cvConvexityDefect gives you the depth you could iterate through all the defects and check that this value falls within the length you would expect from the tip of a finger to the hand. You'll need to look at your hand and work out how many defects there are depending on the amount of fingers you can see.